# Плавная 2D анимация scale в CSS

Tags: css, transform

Добрый вечер!

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.demo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000000;
  transition: 10s;
  display: none;
}

.block:hover .demo {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scaleY(100);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="demo">
  </div>
</div>
```

При наведении на .block высота блока .demo увеличивается мгновенно до 100px. При этом в transition указано 10s. В чем моя ошибка? Спасибо!

Comment: у `transition` несколько параметров.

Comment: Александр, а какого эффекта ты добивался, объясни....

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.demo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000000;
  transition: all 10s;
}

.block:hover .demo {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scaleY(100);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="demo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь можно подробно посмотреть [Transitions on the display: property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

с

```
display: none;
```

анимация не будет работать. Замени

```
display: none;
```

на

```
opacity: 0;
```

и верно будет

```
transition: all 10s;
```

Comment: Попробовал. К сожалению, ничего не изменилось...

Comment: извени, не заметил всего сразу, с display анимация не работает

Comment: Большое спасибо! Работает.

Answer (score 0):

`display: none` не может быть анимировано на css, `opacity: 0` - может.

Раскрытие блока - делаем элемент резко непрозрачным, плавно меняем выстоу. Закрытие блока - плавно меняем высоту, а для прозрачности ставим задержку и резко делаем блок прозрачным.

```
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.demo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000000;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s, opacity 0s ease 0.9s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.block:hover .demo {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scaleY(100);
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o8ubcobj/7/